# Bulk action for custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am working on a wordpress project and I want to add the bulk action on my custom post.

I have used `Custom Post Type` UI plugin for custom post and `Advanced Custom Fields` plugin for custom fields.

Please suggest me any code or plugin to add bulk action for my custom posts.

Thanks,
Aniket.

Answer (score 5):

**Since WordPress 4.7 (released December 2016) it is possible to add custom bulk actions without using JavaScript.**

```
//Hooks
add_action( 'current_screen', 'my_bulk_hooks' );
function my_bulk_hooks() {
    if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
      add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-post', 'register_my_bulk_actions' );
      add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-post', 'my_bulk_action_handler', 10, 3 );
      add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_bulk_action_admin_notice' );      
    }
}   

//Register
function register_my_bulk_actions($bulk_actions) {
  $bulk_actions['email_to_eric'] = __( 'Email to Eric', 'text_domain');
  return $bulk_actions;
}

//Handle 
function my_bulk_action_handler( $redirect_to, $doaction, $post_ids ) {
  if ( $doaction !== 'email_to_eric' ) {
    return $redirect_to;
  }
  foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
    // Perform action for each post.
  }
  $redirect_to = add_query_arg( 'bulk_emailed_posts', count( $post_ids ), $redirect_to );
  return $redirect_to;
}

//Notices
function my_bulk_action_admin_notice() {
  if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['bulk_emailed_posts'] ) ) {
    $emailed_count = intval( $_REQUEST['bulk_emailed_posts'] );
    printf( '<div id="message" class="updated fade">' .
      _n( 'Emailed %s post to Eric.',
        'Emailed %s posts to Eric.',
        $emailed_count,
        'text_domain'
      ) . '</div>', $emailed_count );
  }
}
```

> **Note.1:** You must use `bulk_actions` filters when `WP_Screen` object is defined.That's why I used `current_screen` action in line 2.
>
> **Note.2:** if you want to add bulk action to custom page like woocommerce products page just change screen id in line 5 & 6. Ex: 
> `add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-product', 'register_my_bulk_actions' );`
> `add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-product', 'my_bulk_action_handler', 10, 3 );`

**More information :**

> Using Custom Bulk Actions
>
> https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/10/04/custom-bulk-actions/

Answer (score -3):

use "register_post_type" of WordPress function, It easier than the additional plugins 
Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type